# Azure Databricks cluster configurations

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

For a migration I'm looking to utilize azure databricks to migrate an azure sql database to adls.

The total database will consist of roughly 4000 tables which totals roughly 2.5 TB in size.

I want to use azure databricks to push all the files to adls. The files should be partitioned by year. I'm doing research on the pricing of databricks using the pricing tool from microsoft but am having difficulties in making assumptions of what instance series, workload, VM hours and DBU hours would be appropriate in my scenario.

Does anyone have any experience and can guide me in the right direction of what configurations would be most suitable in my case?

Answer (score 0):

take a look to Azure Data factory, that is more close to the tool you need to execute your data migration, Azure Data Bricks is a platform oriented to data analysis (is running spark behind the scenes), you can create DataFrames and transformations on the platform but extract transform and load data (ETL) is not the main purpose of that tool, if your intention is to migrate several databases and transform the data to store the tables in an ADLS is more the job for an ETL/ELT tool like Azure Data Factory.

To get started take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server?tabs=data-factory